# How to sort these lines with painters algorithm?

Tags: graphics, 3d

Say I am given the following graph and am situated at **eye1**.

[image: Click here for image]

Using painters algorithm, we draw from the back to the front. So if I had to sort the following lines using painters algorithm (e.g. from first drawn to last), I would think it is C, A, E, D, B. What is tripping we up is the surface normal for the lines D and B. Since B's normal is facing away from eye1 and D's is not, does that mean we draw B before D?
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

If back face culling is relevant (i.e. the surface is known to be closed) you don't draw B at all.

Otherwise the direction of the normal plays no role.

Comment: Not sure entirely what you meant by "direction of the normal", but if you are using Newell, Newell, & Sancha's approach to perform the ordering for Painter's algorithm, then the normals *do* play a role, in the sense that you need to know the planes of the triangles/surfaces. These form part of the "P does not obscure Q" (for polygons P & Q) test in the NNS algorithm.

Comment: @SimonF: the OP's question is about the facing side. The isolated faces are opaque from both.

Answer (score 0):

As @Yves-Daoust pointed out, if back-face culling is enabled you can probably discard "B" but, given that your example doesn't have closed geometry, we'll assume it is to be drawn.

> *Aside: BTW did you know there is a  [Computer Graphics](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/) site on SE which caters for these sort of questions?*

Now it's been a few (cough) decades since I studied this, but if you're intending to use [Newell, Newell, & Sancha's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newell%27s_algorithm) to perform the ordering for painters then you will *start* with an initial list of objects, sorted 'furthest to nearest' by max depth, i.e. [C,A,E,D,B], but that list *will* need reordering.

Newell, Newell & Sancha operates as in effect, two nested loops modifying the list. It begins by setting 'P', in the outer loop, to be the furthest item in the list and then steps Q, in the inner loop, through each of the nearer objects, to make sure "*P does not obscure Q*".  It also maintains a per object "was moved" flag to cope with tricky cases.

The '*P does not obscure Q*' test consists of a set of gradually more expensive sub-tests:

1. If P & Q do not overlap in Z at all, P does not obscure Q. (Note that since the list should be sorted, you don't have to test later objects)
2. Bounding box test on screen space X & Y. If there's no overlap, P can't obscure Q.
3. Plane test of P vs Q (and this is where the normal comes in). If all vertices of P lie *behind* the plane of Q, it can't obscure.  Basically, it's a set of dot product calculations.
4. Similarly, if all vertices of Q lie in *front* of the plane of P, it can't obscure.
5. Do a full P vs Q, screen X Y overlap test. This is a bit expensive but if you know there are shared edges etc, you can take some short cuts. Otherwise, you might need to use a separating plane/line algorithm. If there is no overlap, P can't obscure Q.

If P doesn't obscure (all) Qs, then you can draw P and move on to the next furthest and restart the process.

If, OTOH, P does obscure Q, it needs to be moved *after* Q in the list. You also flag that it has been moved. You start again with the (new) 'furthest' item.

In your example, D & B will end up being swapped.

As an added complication, if you find you are about to move an object that has already been moved, then you have a cycle and you'll need to subdivide an object (using one of the planes of the triangles involved - similar to that which arises with building BSPs) but that's another topic.